# Deleteing a bad question with answers

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, deleted-questions

I asked a question which I latter realized was silly. It had already received answers. Should it be deleted or should an answer be accepted?

Comment: As a general rule, you shouldn't delete your own content if it results in other's upvoted content also getting deleted. [In fact, the system will prevent this in most cases, so you couldn't delete your question if there are upvoted answers]. The reason is that even though you might have asked a "silly" question, someone took it seriously enough to answer and others liked it enough to upvote it. As a second general rule, if you missed something, even if it was "silly", it's likely someone else will make the mistake.

Comment: If you think one or more of the answers make worthwhile contributions to the website, I'd encourage you to accept an answer.

Comment: @mixedmath's comment is spot on, especially the second point. Everyone has silly notions from time to time and it's really not uncommon for others to have the same misconceptions. Even if you feel it poorly reflects on you (it doesn't), it could be of benefit to others in the future.

Comment: I guess you can find several older similar discussions. Just two examples I was able to find quickly: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16684/if-my-question-about-proof-verification-is-nonsense-should-i-then-delete-it and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153/what-should-be-deleted-if-i-realize-a-question-is-pointless